# token error when checking if a word exist with for loop and indexOf

Tags: javascript, loops, indexof

I'm trying to check if there the word "@gmail.com" in the user input when the user type anything and if the word is not there, then repeat the question until the user includes the word "@gmail.com" but I'm getting token error in the console with unexpected ), I just started learning loops but wanted to try this idea with only for loops and if statements.

```js
for (var userInput = prompt("enter your email"); userInput.indexOf("@gmail.com") === -1); {
    var userInput = prompt("enter your email");
    if (userInput.indexOf("@gmail.com") !== -1) {
        alert("Welcome");
    }
}
```

Comment: why would you use a loop here? do you want to ask for email untils it contains `@gmail.com` ?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to ask repeatedly, thanks for replying.

Comment: Your code has syntax error here"-1);"

Comment: your code contains lots of syntax errors. Tell us what you intend to do and, surely, we'll help you.

Comment: thanks for replying, I edited it with further explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're for-loop syntax is wrong. It has to have 3 statements in braces, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  //Do something
}
```

The first statement is excecuted **once** when the loop *starts*.
The second statement checks if the code inside the loop should be excecuted.
And the third statement gets excecuted after each loop.

So in your case it would be:

```js
//We ignore the last statement, but have to keep the semicolon!
for (var userInput = prompt("enter your email"); userInput && userInput.indexOf("@gmail.com") === -1; ) {
    userInput = prompt("enter your email");
    if (userInput && userInput.indexOf("@gmail.com") !== -1) {
        alert("Welcome");
    }
}
```

This would be looping with a for-loop like you did, but of course [Félix Brunets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897234/4180937) answer is more elegant for this purpose.

I hope this helps. *-Minding*

Comment: you shoud not have a `var userInput` in the for loop, it as already been declared. you can direcly use `userInput = prompt("enter your email")`

Answer (score 1):

as I understood what you wanted to do :

```
var userInput;
do {
     userInput = prompt("enter your email");
} while(userInput.indexOf("@gmail.com") === -1)
alert("Welcome");
```

It's may not be the best way to do it. With a script like that, you do not check where the "@gmail.com" is, you cannot stop or cancel, etc.

Comment: Looks like it's enough for OP's use case. Client-side validation is not enough anyway, so it doesn't really matter if he uses `indexOf`.

Comment: Thanks!, that's what I wanted to do, this is just for testing and learning purposes but I didn't learn "do" keyword yet, I wanted also to know why It didn't work in the way I have written it.

Comment: note : this is not the `do` keyword but the `do {} while(expression);`.
there is plan for adding a `do`  keyword in javascript in the future, but it is not done at the moment of writing (2018).